# Modifying Javascript in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I've seen this question on multiple forums, but am still unable to find a straight answer on the matter.

I am attempting to make and persist edits to a webpage's main.min.js through Chrome Dev Tools and save the changes. I am able to **edit** the main.min.js (I understand you cannot edit something prettified) but I am unable to save any changes locally, so a reload gets rid of them. Is there a way to persist the edits I make to a .js file through a reload? There is no "Save" option in the Tools after edits are performed. Does this require a userscript API like tampermonkey maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: an extension might help you here, yes

Comment: Try [local overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm mentioned, [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) is the recommended feature for this.

Check what version of Chrome you're running at `chrome://version`. Overrides was introduced in Chrome 65. The feature doesn't exist in earlier versions of Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! Just updated and there it is. I had attempted to use mapping to the local File System to make modifications but this seems like it will be more successful.